# How to fetch user profile in angular client after setting google oauth2 composer rest servers

Tags: google-api, hyperledger, google-oauth

I have set up rest servers as per instructions  https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest

How to fetch user profile in angular client after setting google oauth2 composer rest servers as per the above.

Comment: added google-oauth2 and google-api tags FYI